# Transitioning to a new view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

**So this piece of code is called after authenticating the users login details:**

```
func completeLogin() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let tabBarController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PostLoginTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
            let tableViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InformationTableViewController") as! InformationTableViewController
            let tableViewNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableViewController)
            tabBarController.viewControllers?.removeAll()
            tabBarController.viewControllers?.append(tableViewNavController)
            self.presentViewController(tabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }
```

**In my storyboard:**

[image]

I have the `PostLoginTabBarController` that has a relationship with 2 other `ViewControllers`

**My question is:**

Is there a better way than removing all the `View Controllers` that the `PostLoginTabBarController` has and then adding the new instantiated ones in the `completeLogin()` method? The reason I am doing this is because if I sever the relationship between the `PostLoginTabBarController` when the `PostLoginTabBarController` is presented it shows a black screen, but if I don't sever the relationship then it is fine.

**Here is an example when I sever the relationship:**

[image]

**And when I don't:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, animated animated: Bool)` instead of

```
tabBarController.viewControllers?.removeAll()
tabBarController.viewControllers?.append(tableViewNavController)
```

Comment: Oh yeah that works thanks now I don't even need to connect the view controllers to the tab bar controller